# $\int_\Omega |\nabla u^+|^2 \, dx$ is not differentiable with respect to $u$ in $W_0^{1,2}(\Omega)$

Tags: reference-request, derivatives, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Let $u \in W_0^{1,2}(\Omega)$, where $\Omega$ is some domain in $\mathbb{R}^N$, $N \geq 1$.

Denote $u^+ := \max\{u, 0\}$. (It is know that $u^+$ also belongs to $W_0^{1,2}(\Omega)$ (see, e.g., Theorem A.1 in [Kinderlehrer-Stampacchia](http://books.google.ru/books?id=Z-EyvmfafQ8C&lpg=PP1&hl=ru&pg=PA50#v=onepage&q&f=false)).

Consider now the functional
$$
u \mapsto \int_\Omega |\nabla u^+|^2 \, dx.
$$
It is noted in the [article of M. Clapp & T. Weth](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00526-003-0241-x), p.4, that this functional is *not differentiable* (in the Fréchet sense) in $W_0^{1,2}(\Omega)$.
Unfortunately, they don't provide any reference for a counterexample.

I reinvented the wheel, and constructed a simple 1D counterexample, using the function $u(x) \approx x^\alpha$ near $0$, where $\alpha \in (0,1)$. 
But, obviously, somewhere should be a published result concerning this non-differentiability, which I can cite.

Maybe somebody met the same question and can provide the reference?

Thanks!

P.S. This functional *is* differentiable for $u \in W_0^{1,2}(\Omega) \cap W^{2,2}(\Omega)$ (see [T. Bartsch, T. Weth](http://www-users.mat.uni.torun.pl/~tmna/files/v22n1-01.pdf), Lemma 3.1, p.7).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $\Omega=(0,1)$, define $u_t(x) = x-t$.
Set 
$$
f(t) := \int_\Omega |\nabla u_t^+|^2 dx.
$$
Then it holds $f(t) =1$ for all $t\le 0$, but $f(t) = 1-t$ for $t>0$. If the functional would have been differentiable, so would have been $f$. Thus, the functional is not differentiable.

Edit: To obtain a counter-example in $W-^{1,2}$, my proposal would be:
$\Omega=(-2,2)$. Set $u(x)=|x|$ and $h(x) =1$ for $x\in(-1,1)$. Then extend $u$ and $h$ such that $u,h\in W^{1,2}_0$, $u,h\in C^2(\Omega \setminus[-1,1])$, $u\ge0$ and $h\ge0$, $u'(-2)  >0$, $u'(2)<0$, $h(-2)=h'(2)=0$.

Then $u+th$ should be still non-negative on $\Omega \setminus[-1,1]$ for $|t|$ small. And the integral behaves non-smooth as in the $W^{1,2}$ example above.

Comment: Thanks for your example! However, it is not in $W_0^{1,2}(\Omega)$ space. Is there a simple extension of $u_t(x)$ to $W_0^{1,2}(\Omega)$, which keeps non-differentiability?

Comment: Thank you again. Don't think that I'm finding fault, but that is why I'm asking for a reference - to avoid cumbersome piece of such calculations in my article, and just refer to something.
(Eventually, I constructed a counterexample by myself; but your example is definitely shorter).